# Invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'i' : jump program

Tags: python, literals

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'i'  Everytime I run my program it results in this error any solutions?

```
def jumpIt(lst, n, k, i):
    res = min(n, k) + (int(lst[i]))
    k = n
    n = res
    i = i + 1
    if(i < len(lst)):
        jumpIt(lst, n, k, i)
    else:
        print(res)

def main():
    fileName = "input.txt"
    for line in fileName:
        lst = line.split()
        jumpIt(lst, 0, 0, 0)

main()
```

Comment: What does the first line in your file look like? Please give a sample of the content in the file

Comment: It looks like at some point your line `int(lst[i])` equates to `int('i')` and it throws the exception... print `lst` in your `main()` to debug the issue

Comment: `line` is not a line from your file. It is the characters from the name of your file. You have neglected to actually open the file and are iterating over the name.

Answer (score 3):

You did not open the file for reading. Instead of reading the file contents, you read its name (which, naturally, does not contain digits). Here's what you  really need:

```
def main():
    fileName = "input.txt"
    with open(fileName) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            lst = line.split()
            jumpIt(lst, 0, 0, 0)
```